# Connecting to a SQL Server Compact Edition (.sdf) from an MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, sql-server-ce

I'm building an MFC app in Visual Studio 2008 which classifies textures and I need some sort of lightweight database to hold the characteristics (just some doubles and strings) which can be:

- Carried around with the app on different computers
- Be able to perform queries on it from the app (searches , updates ,inserts ,etc)

Currently I'm looking into SQL Server Compact Edition because it was very easy to create from  Visual Studio (I also need only one table). But I;m having a hard time connecting and updating the database from C++.

This is what I've found on MSDN regarding C++ and SQLCE:

```
public:
 void createSqlCeConnection(){
    SqlCeConnection* myConnection = new SqlCeConnection();
    myConnection->ConnectionString = "DataSource = blabla.sdf";
    MessageBox::Show(String::Format( S"Connection State: {0}", __box(myConnection->State)));
 }
```

Unfortunately my experience with .NET apps is pretty limited.

Hopefully you bright minds could tell me if I'm on the right path and what links and includes should I add for this to work with an C++ MFC projects.

Comment: I recently posted C++ source code for accessing SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases under <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780656/raw-c-code-to-display-the-names-of-tables-in-an-sql-compact-server-using-ole-d/9107697#9107697">Raw C++ code to display the names of tables in an SQL compact server using OLE DB</a>.

Answer (score 3):

For C++ applications, you're going to want to use [the OLE DB Provider for SQL CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174142(v=SQL.100).aspx).  For example, take a look [here for a code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174053(v=SQL.100).aspx) on initializing a Session (you might have to explicitly click the C++ tab in the Examples section).