# What are ways to compress directory into single file

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, directory

Don't know how to ask it so I will explain situation.

I need to store a few compressed files. The original idea was to create a folder and store as many compressed files as were needed and also create a file that holds data about every compressed file.

However, I was not allowed to create many files and must only have one. I decided to create a compressed file which has a header about further data and after header keep compressed data. But this option has disadvantages, e.g. editing such file after it is created takes long time because it must be fully rewritten even if I want to add one more little file.

So, as I imagine, I need to create folder with some specific attributes and create as many files inside. Is this even possible?

I'm creating an app for Windows, so I can use any stuff that works on Windows, and I'm coding with C++.

**NOTE:** A single file is needed because, for example, it will be sent through e-mail and attaching many files is not an ideal solution.

**NOTE:**  I don't need an algorithm for compression, I need some way to efficiently store everything in single file.

Comment: You could probably use [Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this (but you can't use regular file functions with them).

Comment: Since it's Windows, you can use [Alternate Data Streams](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to create more files than you're allowed to, and where does the restriction to one file come from in the first place? Before you create a complicated solution (which will be more difficult to maintain in the long run), have you verified **(a)** that you cannot design your program differently, or **(b)** that you cannot talk your customer into allowing you to create a regular directory (it would likely be for their best, after all)?

Comment: @stakx Regular directory is not allowed, but I have created structure for one single binary file, but it not fast.

Comment: @user2623967: I understand that already; my question was: *Why* is it not allowed, and *why* do you need to do it anyway? (Sometimes it pays off to question the status quo and talk to / convince people to accept a different way of doing things, which might be better in the long run.)

Comment: @stakx I have already made edit to my question about that.

Comment: @user2623967: I see. What stops you from keeping the files in a directory, and zip / compress them *only if and when* they need to be sent over e-mail? (That is, keep your several files in a master directory, then create a ZIP file from that when you need to transfer the data, transfer the ZIP file, then delete it again.)

Comment: Not sure if this is of use, but if you were working in PHP you can do exactly what you describe. There is a feature called PHAR - where you can turn all you files and folders and even images - all into one file. it's not compressed, its just kind of all attached into one big file - perfect to email to people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database, or a SQL Server Compact Edition database (which resides in a single `.sdf` file), and store all your data in there as BLOBs. The database management system should be easy enough to deploy along with the other binaries of your application.

In the case of SQL Server Compact, I am not exactly sure how easy this is to use from unmanaged code (C++). It would be easy enough in .NET, but I'm quite sure it could be done for C++, too &mdash would take some research, though.

At least, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760879/connecting-to-a-sql-server-compact-edition-sdf-from-an-mfc-application) goes into how to connect to such a database from C++ through an OLE DB provider.

Comment: There is not a problem to use `SQLite` with `C++`, but not sure if _the boss_ would like to add more stuff into project, because he is the boss and sometimes he make a good decisions, sometimes not so good, if you know what I mean :)

Comment: @user2623967: Yes, I do. ;-) Sometimes it helps putting your problem into terms of project costs: Reinventing the wheel saves you a dependency on a 3rd party library, but it is usually more expensive (more development time is needed). And might cost more during maintenance because your own solution might have bugs. SQLite, OTOH, is a more mature product and can be expected to work well.

Comment: Your answer probably is best, but `SQLite` doesn't give compression ratio, and compressing and decompressing times is not so much matter, so I stayed with one single file.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the 7zip SDK and save everything in a zip file?

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative, you could use a tar file: an file entry for your custom header with information for the other entries (compression etc.), and all files as entries in the tar file. I don't know exactly how it works to replace an entry with library functions (here I gained the info that it's possible at least with gnu tar http://www.karkomaonline.com/index.php/2005/03/basic-tar-usage-gnu-tar/ command line utility on linux), but it seems that it's possible without recreating the whole archive.
I think you would have to create bigger dummy entries at first to have enough free space available later on, so that these entries will be replaceable with all needed data.