# How to zip / unzip folders in VS2013?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make an app which sends folders to another app using sockets, to deal this maybe zipping / unzipping folders would be the best alternative.

How do I to zip / unzip folders in VS2013, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: -1 Offtopic and duplicate. SO is not a place to ask a tool.[Take a look](https://www.google.lt/?gws_rd=cr&ei=eiIrU67bHKTh4wSn14G4DQ#q=c%2B%2B+compression+library)

Comment: Also if you are working with folder, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330978/what-are-ways-to-compress-directory-into-single-file)might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to zip / unzip folders in Visual Studio (during the build process) then one solution could be to use 7za.exe and a pre- or post- processor command.  You said "in VS2013" but maybe you meant during run time?  If that's the case then I agree with @Reed.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response John, have used before the libs that @Reed have linked?

Comment: I have and they work well if you're using your app to read or generate archives.  7za is more flexible and easier to use outside of an application but difficult to use within a program.

Comment: I'm trying to this while run time. Do you know please how to install these libs, I've tried to include there source code, but this wouldn't work. I think that it's for Linux environment. I'm currently on Windows / Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: libarchive has instructions on their site on how to compile the source code. Start there. Download the windows version, follow the directions to compile, grab the output libraries and include them in your project. Then follow the API documentation.

Comment: would you please link me the first step' link ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like [zziplib](http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/) or [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) to zip your data prior to sending, and unzip on the receiving end.  Both of these libraries support the zip format.

Comment: how to unzip in the other side, do I need to save the full string sent and to create a zip file, unzip it and then remove the zipped file ?

Comment: @Luciekulza Typically you'd work directly from byte data.  I believe both of these libraries support unzipping/zipping from byte data in memory.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much I'll try that. About security, do you advise me to use FTP protocol to the folder transfer or Sockets with zipping and unzipping folders ?

Comment: @Luciekulza That's a huge, separate question on it's own - would need to know a LOT more about your requirements...

Comment: Oh! Sorry, thank you so much. I let you know if this have worked!

Comment: Have you used them before, please? Because I couldn't find how to use these libs.