# Database operations(CRUD) in SqlCE from vc++

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-c++, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I am using visual studio 2008, and want to perform DB operation(CRUD) in sqlCE from VC++.I have to run this code from hardware device like Toradex colibri vf61.

I googled a lot but unfortunately not getting any significant link.So I have no idea where to start?

Comment: Which O/S is installed on targeted devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760879/connecting-to-a-sql-server-compact-edition-sdf-from-an-mfc-application